# How can I increase the size of a div on click by 10% using an event listener?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to simply increase the size of the box by 10% on click. I have left the bottom function in the JavaScript blank because that is where I assume it needs to be inserted. I included the code for the div that is in the html.

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

**JS**

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

function handleClick(event) {

}
```

Comment: Resize the size of a div on click of what? - what is the user going to click on to resize which div?  Looks like the user is going to click on the div itself... is that the intention?

Comment: yes just simply clicking on the div itself to re-size it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple implementation of the scenario:

http://jsbin.com/joxojelami/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Structuring the code this way might not be ideal for a real world application, but works for illustration purposes.
Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS (no JQuery) you could do this:

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

newDiv.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

function handleClick(event) {
  this.style.removeProperty('width');

  var currentWidth = this.offsetWidth;
  alert('current: ' + currentWidth);
  var newWidth = currentWidth * 1.1; // increase by 10%
  //this.offsetWidth = newWidth;
  alert('new: ' + newWidth);
  this.style.setProperty('width', newWidth+'px');
  this.style.setProperty('border-color', 'green');
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get computed style and then add 10% of it to width:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

function handleClick(event) {
   var computedStyle = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(newDiv, null);

   var width=parseInt(computedStyle.width);
   newDiv.style.width=(width * 1.1) + "px";
}
```